# Swift, Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNParticleSystem

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, scenekit

I've just picking up Swift and playing around with SceneKit. I created a simple "Smoke.scnp" particle emitter in the xcode 6 editor, and I'm trying to load that using the SCNParticleSystem class. I have included the SceneKit frame work with the project. When running without the particle system, I could load the camera and other nodes just fine, but including the particle system failed during linking time. The error I got was symbol not found for SCNParticleSystem.

I don't have much experience with SceneKit, so this may not be something specific to xcode6 or Swift. Just wondering if I have to set up anything else?

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var gameView: GameView

    override func awakeFromNib(){

        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()

        // Add camera to scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // Place camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 2)

        // Add particle emitter
        let bgSmokeNode = SCNNode()
        var particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Smoke", inDirectory: "")
        bgSmokeNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(bgSmokeNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like code for a Mac app (using `NSViewController`). Are you running it on OS X v10.9? `SCNParticleSystem` is available only in OS X v10.10 and iOS 8.

Comment: I think that must be it! I'm running on OS X v10.9.